# How can i get website report showing links from each page

Tags: web, analytics

I want to get a report which specifies what all links are there in each page of the website.I tried using different softwares,but the problem is they are just giving all links without showing exactly which links are there in each page.Also the website i am trying to make a report on is very unstructured,so it's not possible to just classify links,based on url forward slashes.For example,links starting with https://example.com/blog, will not give me all links inside the 
'https://example.com/blog' page,because links inside 'https://example.com/blog' page can contains links without 'https://example.com/blog/' in the beginning of the link.

What can i do about this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Google analytics, there is no such concept as the next page.

Rather, it only knows the previous page.

It is due to the disconnected nature of the web.

You can, however, use the previous page to trace back to get the data you want.

Instead of looking for all links inside the https://example.com/blog, you will be looking at getting all links where the previous page is https://example.com/blog

[More detailed explanation](https://help.analyticsedge.com/article/misunderstood-metrics-next-page-path/)